# Open webview when button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, uibutton

I have created a button which should normally open a webview controller. However, it doesn't seem to do anything when I connect the code to the button.

Here is my code:

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *webscanner;
}

-(IBAction)webscanner:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

ViewController.m:

```
@synthesize webView;

-(IBAction)webscanner:(id)sender
{
     NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/reader.html";
    //Create a URL object.
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

     //URL Request Object
     NSURLRequest *webRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     //Load the request in the UIWebView.
     [webView loadRequest:webRequest];
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You should implement webview delegate method `didFailLoadWithError` and `webViewDidStartLoad` to see what is happening.

Comment: Is your webview created with code or storyboard. And is it in the same view as the button is?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I am pretty new to iOS development. Do you have any examples of how these should be implemented?

Comment: @soulshined yes yes, it is

Comment: Do you have your button connected to the code by pressing ctrl+drag -(IBAction) to button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps:-

1)Add `UIWebViewDelegate` in your .h file like that

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController< UIWebViewDelegate > {
```

2)Now implement the below delegate method which will show your web page is loading.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {     
   NSLog(@"page is loading");       
 }

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
       NSLog(@"finished loading");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The page is loading but there must be something wrong with my button. I will try to find a way, thanks anyway!